# I have a data set and I need to create an excel sheet in exact below format...Is there any way to do so?

Tags: sas

Assume here is the data set.....

```
Aspect                                Evaluation      Quarter     Percentage
HOST/HOSTESS DIVERSIONS /687          Excellent       Q1          40%
ROCKIN' BAR D / WAVEBANDS/ EVOLUTION  Excellent       Q1          50%
KNOWLEDGE OF SERVER TEAM – ROTATION   Excellent       Q1          60%
```

Trying to generate below Excel Sheet with same color and Structure, assume the above percentage will be populated in “% Within” column ......

[image]

Any way to get the excel in this required format....?I appreciate any help...
Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to do color and such, you have a few options.  PROC EXPORT won't do it, of course.  So instead, you need to do either Excel Tagsets, DDE, or create an unformatted sheet and use a macro from a template to copy the colors in.

Benefits/Drawbacks:

- Excel Tagsets:

  - Benefits: Make the exact format entirely in SAS code.  Have a great deal of control with a fairly simple interface.  Uses the powerful PROC TEMPLATE to define styles, which allows highly portable and reusable code.
  - Drawbacks: Makes an .xml file that is readable by excel, not actually a .xls/.xlsx file.  Does have some limitations in what it can do.  Can be buggy.  Probably the slowest to code of the three options, unless you are very familiar with it.
- DDE:

  - Benefits: Once you make the template (once) in Excel, can make exactly what you want fully in SAS.   Can do 100% of what Excel does.
  - Drawbacks: Uses somewhat outdated method, so fewer SAS programmers are familiar with it.  Requires Excel to be installed on the machine, and open (you can open it as part of the DDE program).  Somewhat slower to copy data in, and requires more careful checking to verify data went where it should go.  Requires knowing DDE commands.
- Template/copy:

  - Benefits: Likely fastest method in terms of set up time.  Can do everything exactly like what excel does.  Easy for other programmers to understand, as long as they know Excel/VBA and SAS.
  - Drawbacks: requires outside-of-SAS step to run copy macro (could be called from SAS via DDE or batch file, but more commonly would be done by hand).  Does require some knowledge of VBA as well as SAS.

In general, I recommend trying Excel Tagsets first; if they don't work for your needs, try either of the other two options.  Some good papers on Excel Tagsets for the beginner:
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/170-2011.pdf
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/207-2012.pdf
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/036-2008.pdf

I think you could create the above pretty easily using excel tagsets and proc report; follow the first paper in particular as it seems to be the most similar to what you're doing.  If you run into any issues, post them as separate questions and we should be able to help you out.